# Errors While Running 'pip3 install mariadb'

Tags: pip, mariadb

OS : Centos 7

Steps:
`pip3 install mariadb`

Error Details:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PUZF.png

Comment: It is discouraged to post images of text. Just post the text instead, as a quote. Further, this is not a problem that we can reproduce, so it might be hard to receive help.

Comment: It looks like you're missing a C library prereq. See https://mariadb-corporation.github.io/mariadb-connector-python/install.html#prerequisites

Comment: I would point out what exactly the relevant line of your error message is, but I can't because you can't copy-paste text from images.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
yum install mariadb-libs
```

That might solve your error. Then do the `pip3 install mariadb` again.

Comment: I don't think I can help you any further.